# Soffid sync server installation: " Sync server is not configured."

Tags: linux, mariadb

I have a problem installing Soffid.

First I have installed the console and then I have tryed to instal the syncserver following the stepts describe in this video: https://youtu.be/rvnzwefwBqs

When I executed the command to install, the terminal does not aks for the Soffid Sync server configuration.

Command

```
sudo dpkg -i '/Download/SOFFID 3 Sync server-Debian_Ubuntu installer-3.0.1.deb'
```

Log

```
2021-08-31 09:49:452 INFO [main] Waiting ...
2021-08-31 16:22:760 INFO [main] *************************************************
2021-08-31 16:22:763 INFO [main] Soffid IAM Sync Server BOOTSTRAP version 3.0.0
2021-08-31 16:22:766 WARN [main] Sync server is not configured.
2021-08-31 16:22:766 INFO [main] Waiting ...
2021-08-31 16:23:767 INFO [main] Waiting ...
2021-08-31 16:24:768 INFO [main] Waiting ...
2021-08-31 16:25:770 INFO [main] Waiting ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the dpkg configuration, the configuration wizard is allowed to ask for Sync server configuration parameters or not.

Try to execute

```
su soffid -c /opt/soffid/iam-sync/bin/configure
```

It will ask for the configuration settings and the sync server service will resume.